# How do I install GEOS (or libgeos) on Synology NAS?

Tags: python, python-3.x, synology, geos

I've trawled the internet, gone through StackOverflow, GitHub, SynoCommunity and more but I can't seem to find the golden answer to my question;

**Q: How do I install GEOS (or libgeos) on my Synology?**

**The backstory:**
My SO and I have put together a Python3 program to aide us in our search for a house to buy. It pulls some data from various APIs on commute times for public transport and average traffic durations to compile a list of postcodes, computes areas around these postcodes and feeds them to a nationwide house listing service to scrape and spits out the results on a map.

So we know the program works, running it on one of our windows based desktops or a macos laptop gives us exactly what we expect; an HTML file which loads in your browser; displays a map with a bunch of markers showing houses listed for sale.

The modules in python we use are shapely and pickle. GEOS (or libgeos) is a dependancy of shapely for the c library and it is this dependancy that I am having a hard time installing on my NAS.

Why my NAS? Because I have certain parts of my NAS available out to the internet so I can access this from my phone and so I can schedule the scraper on my NAS at night when I don't need my desktop or laptop switched on.

**The technical environment:**
Synology DS1813+
Intel Atom D2700 (cedarview)
DSM 6.2.2-24922
Python3.5.6-8

I have pip installed

shapely installed beautifully through pip aswell as pickle

**What have I found?**
If the elders of the internet are to be believed, installation of GEOS runs through your package manager, grea- oh wait, Synology only has a GUI one and no libgeos there. Ok, so I can install ipkg - but no libgeos there either.

There was an AWESOME Debian Chroot implementation for Synology in the SynoCommunity packages! libgeos has a native debian install available! but for whatever reason (conflicting evidence available), this chroot has since been pulled too with the original developer making various versions available on a request base. But hey, there's a cedarview version! That then calls for Python 2.7.6-8 or later to be installed in an error. But wait.. isn't 3 "or later?" Yup, still no gold. So I installed Python 2.7.6 - still no joy.

Finally I went round the long way of getting to know Docker so I could make my own and then bungled that to the point where if I ever see Docker ever again..... :)))))

**Still reading? Here's the error I got when running the program:**

```
  File "/volume1/@appstore/py3k/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/shapely/geos.py", line 76, in <module>
    free = load_dll('c').free
  File "/volume1/@appstore/py3k/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/shapely/geos.py", line 56, in load_dll
    libname, fallbacks or []))
OSError: Could not find lib c or load any of its variants [].
```

And here's where it comes from in geos.py:

```
lib = find_library(libname)
dll = None
if lib is not None:
    try:
        LOG.debug("Trying `CDLL(%s)`", lib)
        dll = CDLL(lib, mode=mode)
    except OSError:
        LOG.debug("Failed `CDLL(%s)`", lib)
        pass

if not dll and fallbacks is not None:
    for name in fallbacks:
        try:
            LOG.debug("Trying `CDLL(%s)`", name)
            dll = CDLL(name, mode=mode)
        except OSError:
            # move on to the next fallback
            LOG.debug("Failed `CDLL(%s)`", name)
            pass

if dll:
    LOG.debug("Library path: %r", lib or name)
    LOG.debug("DLL: %r", dll)
    return dll
else:
    # No shared library was loaded. Raise OSError.
    raise OSError(
        "Could not find lib {0} or load any of its variants {1}.".format(
            libname, fallbacks or []))
```